# How Can I test POST request with upload file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, multer, supertest

I have a simple node.js with handlebars proyect and I started to do Tests with jest and superTest and I dont know how can I test this POST request with body and file data:

```
app.post('/new-team', upload.single('shield'), (req, res) => {
  const teams = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/teams.db.json'));
  const {
    name, tla, country, address, website, founded,
  } = req.body;
  const state = teams.find((team) => team.tla === tla.toUpperCase());
  if (state) {
    res.render('new-team', {
      layout: 'main',
      data: {
        error: 'Ops! The team you want to create has an existing TLA, try it again',
      },
    });
  } else {
    const newTeam = {
      area: {
        name: country,
      },
      name,
      tla: tla.toUpperCase(),
      country,
      **crestUrl: `/shields/${req.file.filename}`, //HERE IS MY PROBLEM**
      address,
      website,
      founded,
    };
    teams.push(newTeam);
    fs.writeFile('./data/teams.db.json', JSON.stringify(teams), (err) => {
      res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        data: {
          teams,
        },
      });
    });
    res.redirect('/team-created');
  }
  res.render('new-team', {
    layout: 'main',
  });
});
```

I made this to try to send the body:

```
  test('POST /new-team', async () => {
    const newTeam = {
      name: 'rosario central',
      tla: 'CARC',
      country: 'Argentina',
      address: 'colombress 1245',
      website: 'www.central.com',
      founded: '1886',
    };
    const response = await request(baseURL).post('/new-team').send(newTeam);
    expect(response.status).toBe(200);
  });
```

but I dont know how to send the data to have **req.file.filename**

because, I cant access to req.file.filename

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Express endpoint expects a `multipart/form-data` request body. To create one of these with SuperTest / SuperAgent, you can use the `.field()` and `.attach()` methods

```js
const response = await request(baseURL)
  .post("/new-team")
  .field("name", "roasario central")
  .field("tla", "CARC")
  // ... and other fields
  .attach("shield", "fixtures/shield.ext") // attach your file
```

See also the SuperAgent documentation for [Multipart requests](https://ladjs.github.io/superagent/#multipart-requests)